# Opencv build error: relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' ... recompile with -fPIC

Tags: c++, opencv, cmake, libav

I am trying to build opencv like this:

```
wget -nc -O opencv.tar.gz https://github.com/opencv/opencv/archive/4.1.2.tar.gz
wget -nc -O opencv_contrib.tar.gz https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/archive/4.1.2.tar.gz
echo extracting opencv
tar xzf opencv.tar.gz
tar xzf opencv_contrib.tar.gz
mkdir opencv-build
cd opencv-build
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release \
            -D WITH_TBB=ON \
            -D BUILD_PERF_TESTS=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_bioinspired=OFF \
            -D WITH_V4L=ON -D BUILD_opencv_structured_light=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_python2=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_python3=ON \
            -D WITH_CUDA=OFF -D WITH_GSTREAMER=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_stereo=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_gapi=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_objdetect=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_xobjdetect=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_stitching=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_superres=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_surface_matching=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_text=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_face=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_xphoto=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_calib3d=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_core=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_dnn=ON \
            -D BUILD_opencv_cvv=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_world=OFF \
            -D BUILD_TESTS=OFF \
            -D BUILD_opencv_python=OFF \
        -D WITH_QT=ON \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../opencv_contrib-4.1.2/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=OFF ../opencv-4.1.2
  make -j12
```

It seems to be able to configure itself:

```
-- Detected processor: x86_64
-- Looking for ccache - not found
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found suitable version "1.2.11", minimum required is "1.2.3") 
-- Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- libjpeg-turbo: VERSION = 2.0.2, BUILD = opencv-4.1.2-libjpeg-turbo
-- Could NOT find TIFF (missing: TIFF_LIBRARY TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Could NOT find Jasper (missing: JASPER_LIBRARIES JASPER_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.11") 
-- Could NOT find PNG (missing: PNG_LIBRARY PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR) 
-- found Intel IPP (ICV version): 2019.0.0 [2019.0.0 Gold]
-- at: /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
-- found Intel IPP Integration Wrappers sources: 2019.0.0
-- at: /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
-- Could not find OpenBLAS include. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could not find OpenBLAS lib. Turning OpenBLAS_FOUND off
-- Could NOT find Atlas (missing: Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY) 
-- A library with BLAS API not found. Please specify library location.
-- LAPACK requires BLAS
-- A library with LAPACK API not found. Please specify library location.
-- Could NOT find JNI (missing: JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2 JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH) 
-- VTK is not found. Please set -DVTK_DIR in CMake to VTK build directory, or to VTK install subdirectory with VTKConfig.cmake file
-- OpenCV Python: during development append to PYTHONPATH: /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build/python_loader
-- Caffe:   NO
-- Protobuf:   NO
-- Glog:   NO
-- Checking for module 'freetype2'
--   No package 'freetype2' found
-- freetype2:   NO
-- harfbuzz:    YES (ver 1.7.2)
-- Could NOT find HDF5 (missing: HDF5_LIBRARIES HDF5_INCLUDE_DIRS) (found version "")
-- Module opencv_ovis disabled because OGRE3D was not found
-- No preference for use of exported gflags CMake configuration set, and no hints for include/library directories provided. Defaulting to preferring an installed/exported gflags CMake configuration if available.
-- Failed to find installed gflags CMake configuration, searching for gflags build directories exported with CMake.
-- Failed to find gflags - Failed to find an installed/exported CMake configuration for gflags, will perform search for installed gflags components.
-- Failed to find gflags - Could not find gflags include directory, set GFLAGS_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing gflags/gflags.h
-- Failed to find glog - Could not find glog include directory, set GLOG_INCLUDE_DIR to directory containing glog/logging.h
-- Module opencv_sfm disabled because the following dependencies are not found: Eigen Glog/Gflags
-- Checking for module 'tesseract'
--   No package 'tesseract' found
-- Tesseract:   NO
-- Registering hook 'INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn': /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-4.1.2/modules/dnn/cmake/hooks/INIT_MODULE_SOURCES_opencv_dnn.cmake
-- opencv_dnn: filter out cuda4dnn source code
-- 
-- General configuration for OpenCV 4.1.2 =====================================
--   Version control:               3e33837e-dirty
-- 
--   Extra modules:
--     Location (extra):            /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv_contrib-4.1.2/modules
--     Version control (extra):     3e33837e-dirty
-- 
--   Platform:
--     Timestamp:                   2020-05-21T18:21:21Z
--     Host:                        Linux 5.3.0-51-generic x86_64
--     CMake:                       3.10.2
--     CMake generator:             Unix Makefiles
--     CMake build tool:            /usr/bin/make
--     Configuration:               Release
-- 
--   CPU/HW features:
--     Baseline:                    SSE SSE2 SSE3
--       requested:                 SSE3
--     Dispatched code generation:  SSE4_1 SSE4_2 FP16 AVX AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       requested:                 SSE4_1 SSE4_2 AVX FP16 AVX2 AVX512_SKX
--       SSE4_1 (14 files):         + SSSE3 SSE4_1
--       SSE4_2 (1 files):          + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2
--       FP16 (0 files):            + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 AVX
--       AVX (4 files):             + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 AVX
--       AVX2 (27 files):           + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2
--       AVX512_SKX (3 files):      + SSSE3 SSE4_1 POPCNT SSE4_2 FP16 FMA3 AVX AVX2 AVX_512F AVX512_COMMON AVX512_SKX
-- 
--   C/C++:
--     Built as dynamic libs?:      YES
--     C++ Compiler:                /usr/bin/c++  (ver 7.5.0)
--     C++ flags (Release):         -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C++ flags (Debug):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wsign-promo -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wsuggest-override -Wno-delete-non-virtual-dtor -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -fvisibility-inlines-hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     C Compiler:                  /usr/bin/cc
--     C flags (Release):           -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -O3 -DNDEBUG  -DNDEBUG
--     C flags (Debug):             -fsigned-char -W -Wall -Werror=return-type -Werror=non-virtual-dtor -Werror=address -Werror=sequence-point -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wmissing-declarations -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wundef -Winit-self -Wpointer-arith -Wshadow -Wuninitialized -Winit-self -Wno-comment -Wimplicit-fallthrough=3 -Wno-strict-overflow -fdiagnostics-show-option -Wno-long-long -pthread -fomit-frame-pointer -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections  -msse -msse2 -msse3 -fvisibility=hidden -g  -O0 -DDEBUG -D_DEBUG
--     Linker flags (Release):      -Wl,--gc-sections  
--     Linker flags (Debug):        -Wl,--gc-sections  
--     ccache:                      NO
--     Precompiled headers:         NO
--     Extra dependencies:          dl m pthread rt /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
--     3rdparty dependencies:
-- 
--   OpenCV modules:
--     To be built:                 aruco bgsegm calib3d ccalib core datasets dnn dnn_objdetect dnn_superres dpm features2d flann fuzzy gapi hfs highgui img_hash imgcodecs imgproc line_descriptor ml objdetect optflow phase_unwrapping photo plot python3 quality reg rgbd saliency shape tracking video videoio videostab xfeatures2d ximgproc xobjdetect
--     Disabled:                    bioinspired cvv face stereo stitching structured_light superres surface_matching text world xphoto
--     Disabled by dependency:      -
--     Unavailable:                 cnn_3dobj cudaarithm cudabgsegm cudacodec cudafeatures2d cudafilters cudaimgproc cudalegacy cudaobjdetect cudaoptflow cudastereo cudawarping cudev freetype hdf java js matlab ovis python2 sfm ts viz
--     Applications:                apps
--     Documentation:               NO
--     Non-free algorithms:         NO
-- 
--   GUI: 
--     QT:                          YES (ver 5.9.5)
--       QT OpenGL support:         YES (Qt5::OpenGL 5.9.5)
--     GTK+:                        NO
--     OpenGL support:              YES (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so)
--     VTK support:                 NO
-- 
--   Media I/O: 
--     ZLib:                        /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (ver 1.2.11)
--     JPEG:                        libjpeg-turbo (ver 2.0.2-62)
--     WEBP:                        build (ver encoder: 0x020e)
--     PNG:                         build (ver 1.6.37)
--     TIFF:                        build (ver 42 - 4.0.10)
--     JPEG 2000:                   build (ver 1.900.1)
--     OpenEXR:                     build (ver 2.3.0)
--     HDR:                         YES
--     SUNRASTER:                   YES
--     PXM:                         YES
--     PFM:                         YES
-- 
--   Video I/O:
--     DC1394:                      YES (2.2.5)
--     FFMPEG:                      YES
--       avcodec:                   YES (58.71.100)
--       avformat:                  YES (58.38.101)
--       avutil:                    YES (56.41.100)
--       swscale:                   YES (5.6.100)
--       avresample:                YES (3.7.0)
--     v4l/v4l2:                    YES (linux/videodev2.h)
-- 
--   Parallel framework:            pthreads
-- 
--   Trace:                         YES (with Intel ITT)
-- 
--   Other third-party libraries:
--     Intel IPP:                   2019.0.0 Gold [2019.0.0]
--            at:                   /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/icv
--     Intel IPP IW:                sources (2019.0.0)
--               at:                /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build/3rdparty/ippicv/ippicv_lnx/iw
--     Lapack:                      NO
--     Eigen:                       NO
--     Custom HAL:                  NO
--     Protobuf:                    build (3.5.1)
-- 
--   OpenCL:                        YES (no extra features)
--     Include path:                /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-4.1.2/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
--     Link libraries:              Dynamic load
-- 
--   Python 3:
--     Interpreter:                 /usr/bin/python3 (ver 3.6.9)
--     Libraries:                   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpython3.6m.so (ver 3.6.9)
--     numpy:                       /home/stiv2/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include (ver 1.18.1)
--     install path:                lib/python3.6/dist-packages/cv2/python-3.6
-- 
--   Python (for build):            /usr/bin/python2.7
-- 
--   Java:                          
--     ant:                         NO
--     JNI:                         NO
--     Java wrappers:               NO
--     Java tests:                  NO
-- 
--   Install to:                    /usr/local
-- -----------------------------------------------------------------
-- 
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/stiv2/jsoft-1.0/opencv-build
```

but when I make it, I suddenly get this:

```
[ 78%] Linking CXX shared library ../../lib/libopencv_videoio.so
/usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a(vc1dsp_mmx.o): relocation R_X86_64_PC32 against symbol `ff_pw_9' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
/usr/bin/ld: final link failed: Bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/build.make:415: recipe for target 'lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.1.2' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/libopencv_videoio.so.4.1.2] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:3689: recipe for target 'modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [modules/videoio/CMakeFiles/opencv_videoio.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:162: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

what is this and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you seen this [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19768349/3987854)? You're probably linking against a static `.a` library that didn't compile with `-fPIC`. You can try removing the `.a` library to see if it finds the `.so` shared library instead (if it exists). Or, you can find and install an `-fPIC` version of `libavcodec.a`. Or, build all of your libraries as static libraries as well. This [response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34886150/recompile-with-fpic-error-persists-even-after-adding-fpic-compile-flag) also seems relevant.

Comment: I am just running cmake, i don't know where I should search for .a library...

Comment: The error message claims the library is here: `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.a`. Does this library exist? Are there shared libraries `/usr/local/lib/libavcodec.so` located there as well?